# when to use didn't and when to say don't

Tags: tense, past-tense

During my school days, my English teacher taught us that there is something called
double past. For example - you don't say -

1. I didn't went to school yesterday.
   -> He said with didn't you don't use another past verb form.

So, he corrected us

1. I didn't go to school yesterday.

#

Now, I am a bit confused here.

Incorrect Sentence -
1. She would hold my bicycle from the back to ensure that I don't fell down.

Correct One-

She would hold my bicycle from the back to ensure that I didn't fell down.

> > I am confused here - didn't + fell -> isn't a double past?

What am I missing here? I have seen that I do this mistake a lot.  Please help.

Comment: "Didn't fell" and "don't fell" are both wrong: it should be "didn't fall".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> He said with didn't you don't use another past verb form.

This is a good heuristic, though I don't recall anything about "double past" in school myself.  But it still works.

The technical way to say it is "*do* can take an auxillary/helping verb, but the only valid auxillary/helping verb for *do* is the plain or infinitive form (same as present tense)."

> She would hold my bicycle from the back to ensure that I don't fell down.

The one you say is correct -

> She would hold my bicycle from the back to ensure that I didn't fell down.

is still not correct (if someone told you it was, they are wrong).

Following your heuristic, the right answer is:

> She would hold my bicycle fro mthe back to ensure that I didn't *fall* down.

Comment: Is this correct ? She would hold my bicycle from the back to ensure that I don't fell down.

Comment: @dexterous_stranger: no, it is not correct. As LaurenceC said, when you used **do** it becomes the main verb in the sentence, and you have to used the other verb in the infinitive (fall) . Here is another example: you can say "Make sure that he goes to school". Note that **he** requires third person of the verb **goes**.  Now add a **do**: "make sure that he **does** go to school". You can see that **does** is now in the third person, and **go** is  now in the infinitive.